# Xcode SpriteKit LevelBuilder

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

Im trying to use the level editor from Xcode, but i can't seem to add anything but plane old rectangles.

Here is what i have, but i would like to have circles instead of rectangles:

[image]

I know i can add circles and various shapes programatically, but it would really convinient to add them from interface builder / level editor.

If there is no way, how would I achieve desired functionality?

Should i use rectangles in interface builder to be used as placeholders, and then replace them in the code?

Or is just to much to ask from a simple level editor, and i should just create my circles with code only?

Answer (score 1):

You could create (in photoshop, sketch, etc..) a circle image any size/shape you choose and add it to the Assets.xcassets file. Then add your Color Sprite (the red rectangle ) and choose your image in the texture box under the attributes inspector.  You could use it as temporary placeholder or the actual image you intend to use.

[SpriteKit Level Editor image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYPwO.png)